# is it possible to get jOrg chart should be vertical

Tags: jquery, html

I am following this link to get jorgchart...

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/ndt02yjc/>?
```

it's getting Horizontal Structure, is it possible to get vertical.

If anyone knows please help me to get sove this.

Comment: What do you mean by Vertical Structure?  Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Hi I need horizontal....i am little bit confused about structure...ok please can we change the structure as horizontal

Comment: http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

Comment: i need my jorg chart as above link...please try to help me...